# Full URL of the error page in JSF page

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I config error page in web.xml as following:

```
<error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error/error500.jsf</location>
</error-page>
```

So whenever an error 500 occures, it comes to error500.jsf page. Here I need to get the full URL of the error occured page.

ie If I get an exception in processing the page :

> http://localhost/pc/ui/oligo-home?product=oligo

I need to get the product parameter in my error500.jsf page.

I am getting
 `/pc/ui/oligo-home` using  #{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.request_uri']}.

But I need to get the product also in JSF.

My purpose is to pass these product parameter  as an argument to a method in the backing managedbean of error500.jsf page. So I need to get it in error500.jsf page. I dont want to get it using javascript.

I am passing like this :

```
<f:ajax event="click" execute='form' listener="#{emailManagedBean.sendEmailForErrorPage(product)}" render="form"  />
```

I need to get the product.
Can someone help me out.

Comment: I would store the product into a field of a session scoped bean.

Comment: I am using request scoped

Comment: Is not the error page a different request?

Comment: Yes error page have different request. That is the issue. We cant get it from request. Is there any way?

Comment: Yes, use a `session` scoped bean...

Comment: But I am not supposed to use session scoped. We are using only request scoped.